# Hadoop eclipse plugin 2.6 - An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status updater". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop2

When adding a new Hadoop location in the Eclipse Hadoop plugin 2.6, and trying to expand the location, I have this error

> An internal error occurred during: "Map/Reduce location status
>   updater". java.lang.NullPointerException

Please see the pictures below :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiGch.jpg .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrIrK.jpg .

By the way, what part of configuration in hadoop do I need to configure for the "Map/Reduce(V2) Master Section ? For me, the port 54333 is not listening in the Master server, could this be the error ?

I'm running eclipse localy with a remote hadoop cluster

I have tried with different version of Eclipse and got the same error

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, is your hadoop in the version 2.6?

Secondly, the map/reduce master host and port you set in the https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrIrK.jpg should be consistent with the port in the mapred.job.tracker setting of the file mapred-site.xml. It is 9001 in my case.

Thirdly, the dfs mater host and port should be consistent with the fs.default.name in the file core-site.xml. In my case, it is 9000.

Last but not least, you need set the advance parameters. Here are the steps:
1. go the advanced parameters
2. find hadoop.tmp.dir, put the configuration consistent with core-site.xml.
http://images.cnitblog.com/blog/574931/201401/02101234-fa73442479c041a48cafeb36af554f44.png
3. Restart the eclipse
4. Check the connection

Because I don't have 10 reputation, so I cannot post images to you.... Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

"NullPointerException" is just Because you don't have any directory in your hdfs.

Try that to build a directory:

```
bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir –p ~/input
```

and the error is gone.